# Why include minimum SDK version when you have AppCompatActivity and the standard library?

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

If `AppCompatActivity` and the standard library handle the usage of newer APIs in previous versions of Android, why do you need to specify a minimum SDK level?

Comment: In addition to what Gabe wrote, the libraries that you use have a minimum API level that they support. Nothing much supports all the way back to API Level 1 (Android 1.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the support library doesn't fix everything.  It can't fix some things-  there are features that require hardware support.  Or are too big to backport.  For those you need a way to specify what versions of the SDK aren't supported, hence the minimum SDK level.

Also the framework DOESN'T handle calling newer functions on older SDK versions.  If you call a function added in v26 on v24, you'll crash.